# Kotlin function that returns 0 for negative values and the same value for positive ones

Tags: kotlin

I'm a bit annoyed with the line of code below. I'm wondering if there are any build-in function in the Kotlin SDK that could do the same in a more elegant way.

```
val result = if (value > 0) value else 0
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
val result = value.coerceAtLeast(0)
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/coerce-at-least.html

also you can use

```
val result = max(0, value)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :)